# JCL - Get count of non space chars in a given area (mainframe)

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I need to prepare some input data to run through a program, the data should be in the following format.

```
 UID (1-11)|TxtLen (12-16)| Text (17-62)
```

I can use sort to position the fields properly and get the UID and text fields.
The ‘TxtLen’ is should contain the number of chars from the start of the text field to the last char in the text field.

```
i.e. “Hello”’s TxtLen is 5, “Hel lo”’s TxtLen is 6, “Hello World”’s TxtLen is 11, etc...
```

I want to know if there is a way of getting the TxtLen through JCL only, or is a program required to do this?

-Thanks

Comment: Do you want records chars or the number of chars between two positions?

Comment: You'd need about 45 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(logexp statements, but they'd be very similar. So, yes, you could do the whole thing with Sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need a program.

I see a fair number of mainframe questions on Stack Overflow asking if something is possible with "JCL only."  Keep in mind that [JCL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zmjug-introduction) is mostly a means of executing programs, and actually does very little other than that.  For instance, when you say

> I can use sort to position the fields properly and get the UID and
> text fields

`sort` is a program.  It happens to be a program found on most systems (though there are different vendors' implementations, IBM has one, SyncSort has one, CA has one, etc.)  There are [plenty of other programs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=introduction-data-set-utility-programs) commonly found on mainframe systems.

And just to be pedantic, JCL doesn't actually do *anything*, [JES](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=introduction-jes2) does the work as it interprets JCL.

For your particular situation you could create a SORT exit, or process your data in [Rexx](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=tsoe-zos-rexx-reference), or you could use some of the [Unix System Services](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-zos-unix-system-command-reference) [commands](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-shell-command-descriptions) and execute those via [BPXBATCH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=environments-bpxbatch) or [COZBATCH](http://www.dovetail.com/products/cozbatch.html).

Comment: Agreed, if you want it in JCL, it normally means you need to tweak it without repackaging compiled code.  So REXX or Eztrieve or the higher utilities are used.

Answer (score 1):

I've done ad-hoc conversions like this using a REXX program. The program is pretty straight-forward:

- allocate the input and output files
- open both files
  begin loop:
- read the input
- extract the text field and strip trailing spaces
- get length of trimmed text field and format as 5-digit numeric
- overlay number back into record in the Len field positions
- write out updated record
  repeat loop until end of file
- close both files
- free allocated files

Let me know if you need some actual code. I've found that REXX is superior than COBOL when it comes to string functions and manipulations. I've even created and called REXX routines from COBOL to accomplish just that.