# add numbers from several input files into 1 file using JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have n number of files that have a particular count.
I now want to add all those count values into another file.

it will be something like

```
//SORTIN   DD file1
//         DD file2
              .
           DD filen
//SORTOUT  DD output file
```

need a way to do the same using only JCL.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. You wish to use a SORT utility invoked from JCL. This is not "only JCL". JCL is involved, but the real work is being done by SORT.

Comment: The question is still vague. Is the count the record count, or a field in the records.  On the face of it this was an ICETOOL or SYNCTOOL candidate.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your "using only JCL" requirement, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076078/jcl-get-count-of-non-space-chars-in-a-given-area-mainframe/11076336#11076336).

If your files are GDGs then in your SORTIN just specify the GDG base name without specifying a generation number.  The system will automatically concatenate your files for you.

Comment: Be acutely aware that when this is done, it is done on a LIFO basis.  The most recent generation is read first.   Important if any other processing depends on the historical order of the records and you are not just counting them.

Comment: @mckenzm z/OS 2.1 includes facilities to read GDGs in chronological order

Comment: Thank you for that, I was not aware of it yet. That will save quite a few sorts.