# Sort and Join of GDG file and DB2 table

Tags: jcl

I have one GDG file and DB2 table.
I want to compare the value (column 45-52) from GDG file with one of the column in DB2 table.
Is it possible to compare and join the file and table in JCL.
If so, please give me a sample code

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "in JCL" please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076078/jcl-get-count-of-non-space-chars-in-a-given-area-mainframe/11076336#11076336).

In answer to your question, yes it can be done.  You must unload the DB2 data into a flat file using whatever utilities are available at your shop, SyncSort, DSNTEP4, etc.  Then you can join that flat file with your GDG using your SORT utility (SyncSort JOINKEYS, DFSORT JOINKEYS).