# Adding a new column in SORT

Tags: mainframe, jcl, syncsort, dfsort

My input data is like this:

```
trainnumber name   station     price  coach seats

16001 CHN-CENTRAL PALANI      400.00 AC  02 

16002 PALANI      CHN-CENTRAL 410.00 ORD 76 

16003 CHN-CENTRAL NAGARKOIL   425.00 AC  30 

16004 NAGARKOIL   CHN-CENTRAL 439.00 SLP 37 

16005 THANJAVUR   CHN-EGMORE  395.00 ORD 60 

16006 CHN-EGMORE  THANJAVUR   375.00 SLP 10
```

I want to add a new column before train number containing a four-digit sequence number followed by a blank and add 1 to my train number.
How to do this?

Comment: I assume that by "JCL" you mean your SORT product?

Comment: Regarding "in JCL", please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076078/jcl-get-count-of-non-space-chars-in-a-given-area-mainframe/11076336#11076336 for a brief explanation of why that's not your best foot forward.

Comment: yes by sort i have to do this i need to add new column(serial number column) with length of 4 and i need to add 1 to my train number how to do this?

Comment: Some response on your previous question would be nice. You should consider voting on answers you think helpful and here you should Accept the answer that helps you most, even if it is yours. This can assist future searches for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY                                      
OUTREC FIELDS=(1:SEQNUM,4,ZD,X,6:1,5,ZD,ADD,+1,EDIT=(TTTTT),
  X,12:7,69)
```

Simplified:

```
OPTION COPY                                      
INREC BUILD=(SEQNUM,4,ZD,
             X,
             1,5,ZD,
              ADD,+1,
               EDIT=(TTTTT),
             X,
             7,69)
```

OUTREC runs after a SORT/MERGE. INREC runs before a SORT/MERGE. Since you're not doing a SORT or MERGE (you're doing a COPY) it doesn't matter, but INREC is the more logical choice.

FIELDS is overloaded (consult the documentation to confirm) and since the presence of BUILD, FIELDS is not needed on INREC or OUTREC (and OUTREC is not needed on OUTFIL) because BUILD does the same job but with no possible confusion (BUILD is a synonym for FIELDS on INREC and OUTREC and OUTREC on OUTFIL - already complicated, without considering FIELDS on SUM, REFORMAT...).

Don't specify column positions (like 1:) if the positions are simply the natural arrangement. You are just building in maintenance.

The default start-point for a BUILD (or even the ugly FIELDS) is 1:. The default for the next field is immediately after the current field. You've used X for the spacing of your columns, so all data abuts the previous data. Using columns just complicates it.

Note: you have X,7,69. You could consider changing that to just 6,69, because position six is blank on your input.

Note: you are "losing" six bytes of your 80-byte record. If your input has, guaranteed, twelve trailing blanks (or other data that you do not require, ie any program using the file doesn't care about that loss) then that's OK, but we can't tell from your description.

Try to make your SORT Control Cards easier to read (try to make everything easier to read). It will save time and reduce errors. Which means cheaper. Time is money.

---

Assuming that you do mean with SORT, and your "column" isn't for DB2....

For fixed-length records:

```
OPTION COPY
INREC BUILD=(5X,1,your-lrecel)
```

The BUILD will cause a new current record, replacing the original, to be created. It will start with five blanks (the 5X) but you can put there whatever you like of whatever size (within the limits of the product, which are large). Change your-lrecl to the actual LRECL value.

For variable-length records:

```
OPTION COPY
INREC BUILD=(1,4,5X,5)
```

The 1,4 is the Record Descriptor Word, and it is always necessary to copy an RDW when creating a new current record. Once it is copied, SORT will ensure that the value contained in the first two bytes (the record-length) is correct. Then the new column, again five blanks in the example, then the rest of the variable-length record, which is specified simply by using a start-position (five here, to get the first byte of data) and implicitly this continues to the end of the record.

In your actual JCL (none of the above is JCL, it is SORT Control Cards), ensure that you do not specify any DCB info for SORTOUT. This means you can't use LIKE for that DD, remember that adding data makes the new LRECL different. Don't code the new LRECL in the JCL either. With it not specified, SORT will insert the correct value, and there is only one place to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this and I did it.

```
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                      
  OUTREC FIELDS=(1:SEQNUM,4,ZD,X,6:1,5,ZD,ADD,+1,EDIT=(TTTTT),
    X,12:7,69)
```

My file is 80 record length.