# Find and delete dynamic string using JCL

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I have a requirement.

Read a record, and find a 5 byte string starting with 'Q' (eg: Q$A12), and delete the string from record.

This 5 digit string can be present anywhere in the record. The string starting with 'Q' and rest of the 4 bytes can be vary. My record length is 15 bytes.

I have to do this using SORT.

Example:

**Input:**

```
ABCDEFG123**QABC2**
ACDHLAMANWST2HY
HAI**Q&A12**ACMATLK
```

**Output:**

```
ABCDEFG123 
ACDHLAMANWST2HY
HAIACMATLK
```

Comment: @Bill Woodger, I have already answered there,
If the record have 'Q****', then delete that string or replace with ' '(spaces). 
If there is no 'Q****' in the record, then no need to do anything.(write the actual data to output),
yes, there can be blank also in the data

Comment: First, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076078/jcl-get-count-of-non-space-chars-in-a-given-area-mainframe/11076336#11076336 with respect to your "with JCL" requirement.  Second, show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  OPTION COPY 

  INREC IFOUTLEN=15, 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT, 
                 FINDREP=(IN=C' ', 
                          OUT=X'FE')), 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT, 
                 FINDREP=(IN=C'Q', 
                          OUT=X'FD', 
                          STARTPOS=12)), 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT, 
                 PARSE=(%00=(ENDBEFR=C'Q', 
                             FIXLEN=15), 
                        %01=(SUBPOS=1, 
                             STARTAT=C'Q', 
                             FIXLEN=5), 
                        %02=(FIXLEN=10)), 
                 BUILD=(%00, 
                        X'FEFEFEFEFE', 
                        %02)), 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT, 
                 OVERLAY=(1,30, 
                           SQZ=(SHIFT=LEFT))),
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT, 
                 FINDREP=(IN=X'FE', 
                          OUT=C' ')), 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT, 
                 FINDREP=(IN=X'FD', 
                          OUT=C'Q'))
```

Set the length of the output records to 15.

Change all original blanks to a non-display character (assuming you data is display-only).

Change any Qs which are not followed by four bytes to another non-display character.

Use PARSE to split input into up to three fields: data before Q (if present, else all data); Five bytes starting with Q; remainder (when Q is present and not in the final position).

Use BUILD to generate a new record, with the space-value, five of them, if necessary to set Q-data to space. User OVERLAY to remove trailing blanks from the fields.

Change space-values back to space. Change Q-value back to Q.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill Woodger. your answer is perfect :)